# iOS: DequeTableViewCell..a little bit confused

Tags: ios, tableview

I want to alter the font size and color etc. for my `UITableView` cells. I've designed the cells  custom in `Xcode` and got everything working.

First of I'll post my code here:
`UITableViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:MainCategoryTableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MainCategoryCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCategoryCell";
    MainCategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

And my custom cell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.title.font = [Theme tableCellTitleFont];
        self.title.textColor = [Theme tableCellTitleColor];

        self.subcategories.font = [Theme tableCellSubTitleFont];
        self.subcategories.textColor = [Theme tableCellSubTitleColor];

        self.costs.font = [Theme tableCellValueFont];
        self.costs.textColor = [Theme tableCellValueColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'm confused now how this dequeue works:
As far as I understood if I register the class in the `viewDidLoad`, the `initWithStyle` method of the cell gets ONLY called, when theres no cell for reuse. If theres a cell for reuse it will be used. I've seen a lot of if(cell == nil) calls in other code snippets but is that really necessary? I thought the `registerClass` method takes care of that anyway?

And at the moment my cells will be displayed completely empty. Before I registered the class everything worked, however the `initWithStyle` didn't get called..

Complete `cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod`:

```
#pragma mark Delegate methods
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCategoryCell";
    MainCategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.title.text = mainCategory.name;
    cell.subcategories.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i subcategories", [[mainCategory getNumberOfSpendingCategories] integerValue]];
    cell.costs.text = [[mainCategory getMonthlyCostsOfAllSpendingCategories] getLocalizedCurrencyString];
    if(!mainCategory.icon){
        cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultIcon.png"];
    } else {
        cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:mainCategory.icon];
    }

    if(!mainCategory.color){
        cell.backgroundColor = [PresetColor colorForPresetColor:PresetColorsWhite];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [PresetColor colorForPresetColor:(PresetColors)[mainCategory.color intValue]];
    }

    cell.cellBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"content-bkg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have defined the cell as "prototype cell" for the table view in the xib/storyboard file, then you don't have to register it at all. If the custom cell is in a separate nib file, you register the custom cell with `registerNib`, not `registerClass`. For example:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MainCategoryTableViewCell" bundle:nil]
      forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MainCategoryCell"];
```

For cells instantiated from a nib file, `initWithCoder` is called, not `initWithStyle`.

To configure any outlets of your custom cell, override `awakeFromNib`. The connections are
not yet established in `initWithCoder`.

Comment: Why in the world would you assume this? `-registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` is perfectly valid and is intended for use with a `UITableViewCell` subclass like the one this question asker seems to be using.

Comment: No I actually have a prototype cell in Xcode (not a special Nib file) and just want to adjust the font color and type for the cell. And I'm confused about this dequeue and what gets called when

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon: The OP said in the question *"I've designed the cells custom in Xcode ..."*, therefore I assumed that he designed the cell in a nib/storyboard file and therefore my answer might be useful (and not a candidate for a downvote).

Comment: @MichiZH: I am not sure what you mean with *"prototype cell in Xcode (not a special Nib file) "*, where exactly have you designed the cell? - Can you try if `initWithCoder` and `awakeFromNib` is called?

Comment: @MichiZH Michi, is the cell you designed included in your nib/storyboard as a prototype cell? If it is, then your `-registerClass:...` call is conflicting with what the nib already did for you.

Comment: Yes it is a prototype cell. So I can only do either prototype or register? But where would you then define text font and color in code if you're using prototype cells?

Comment: @MichiZH: A prototype cell is automatically registered. Use initWithCoder to init instance variables and awakeFromNib (don't forget to call "super") to configure UI elements such as fonts for the labels etc.

Comment: @MichiZH: IB's Identity inspector (second tab from the left in the rightmost pane of Xcode) lets you specify a subclass for a particular object in the nib file to use. Select the cell, open that inspector, and type the name of your subclass into the box.

Answer (score 1):

For best understanding see the below image for just a deque reference.

Deque means you can add and delete cells from both the ends.

By ends I mean up and down.

Lets say you have 4 cell containg Acell,Bcell,Ccell and Dcell and height for row is for three cells.

so at a time only 3 cells would be visible.

when you scroll to see the Dcell , Acell would become as invisible row and memory for it will be reused for Dcell.

In the same way when you scroll to see the Acell , Dcell would become as invisible row and memory for it will be reused for Acell.

[image: Help]

Answer (score 0):

It says clearly in documentation

> dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
>
> For performance reasons, a table view's data source should generally
>   reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in its
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A table view maintains a
>   queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has
>   marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when
>   asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues
>   an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the
>   class or nib file you previously registered.

.

> dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
>
> Return Value : A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier
>   or nil if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.
>
> Discussion  : For performance reasons, a table view's data source
>   should generally reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells
>   to rows in its tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A table view
>   maintains a queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data
>   source has marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source
>   object when asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This
>   method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new
>   one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell
>   is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file,
>   this method returns nil.
>
> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell
>   must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its
>   initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this
>   method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an
>   existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s
>   prepareForReuse method instead.

Before introducing storyboard.The tableview checks the returned cell which can be nil .So if nil we must reallocate the cell and tehn initialize and provide the cell in the datasource method

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get it. I've read through the documentation before and as far as I understand I did everything correctly. Because I've registered the class, I don't have to check for nil and the init gets called automatically. However what I don't understand is that I don't have any values set in my cells. In the viewDid Load method between the dequeue call and return cell I set all the labels and text boxes. But all cells in my table view are empty at the moment...

Comment: Filling the value is the job of datasource method .It is not supposed to be implemented inside tableviewcell class.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do, in the view did load of the view controller I fill the values. However, they don't get filled. I only set the font and font color in the table view cell.

Comment: I said it .YOu must implement datasource method properly Refer this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: I pasted now the complete cellForRowAtIndexPath code into my question…I've implemented everything correctly or not?